# (Delphi 7) Object drawn on canvas (and the canvas itself) does not appear

Tags: delphi, canvas

I've been trying to display a rectangle by creating a canvas on a bitmap. It looks like this:

```
  TRoom = class
   private
     width, length, X1,X2,Y1,Y2, index: integer;
   public
     plane: TBitmap;
     procedure draw;
     procedure setparam;
     function getparam: integer;
  end;


procedure TRoom.draw;
begin
  plane:= TBitmap.create;
  plane.canvas.Pen.Color:= 1791767;
  plane.Canvas.pen.Width:= 3;
  plane.canvas.Rectangle(10,10,20,20);
end;
```

As stated in the title, neither the canvas, nor the rectangle appear. 
I have never worked with the canvas in Delphi before so I expect it to be something rather trivial.

Comment: You are drawing on a bitmap canvas. That's where you ended up. Now you can render this bitmap on some control canvas to see the result.

Comment: Where do you want the image to appear? Do you have a form?

Comment: @TLama How exactly do I do this? I cannot use the Objects of my Form. I've tried to create an image canvas but this yielded similar results

Comment: You are create a new `TBitmap` object referenced by `plane` every time when your drawing something on it. I guess that you have to create `plane` object at creating `TRoom` object and then reuse it.

Answer (score 2):

A `TBitmap` is a non visual class that represents a raster image, a 2D array of pixels. On its own it is never visible. You would need to paint it on the screen in order to see it.

What you should do is create a visual control to which you can paint. For instance a `TPaintBox`. Put one of those on your form and add a handler for its `OnPaint` event.

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TCanvas);
begin
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color :=. 1791767;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 3;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20);
end;
```